# What is the equivalent gcloud API to retrieve user-group mapping list?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to get a way to list what all groups a user is part of in GCP. Is there a gcloud API available to query this feature?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Resource Manager API](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/) to manage and query user permissions for Google Cloud Platform projects.

To address your specific question, you can use the [resourcemanager.projects.getIamPolicy](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/getIamPolicy) call to return the access control policy for a specified project in JSON format using an HTTP request.

You can also use the code snippets to access the API and return a response with the roles and members using different languages.

Alternatively, you can use this [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/get-iam-policy) `gcloud projects get-iam-policy example-project-id-1` to get the IAM policy for a project using the ID to get the same JSON response.

It is worth pointing out that there is no call that gets roles for a specific user directly. You have to parse the JSON response from the call and get roles programmatically for a specific member.